# Android above 11: Do not display the "Screen is pined" modal always

Tags: android

I have an Android application > 11 with “Kiosk” functionality.
I use the "pined" functionality which works very well, my problem is that I have the "Screen is pined" "modal" which is systematically displayed each time I re-pin the app, which is normal .

I'm trying to no longer display this "modal". Is it possible ?
I looked on the internet for MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_LOCK_TASK but without understanding how it works.

[Show modal picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BU1C.png)

I searched the internet for a long time without finding a clear answer to my answer or whether what I want to do is possible or not.